# picking up records from a SQL query result based on rank

Tags: sql-server, rank, row-number

I am testing a complex database rule and I need help to formulate logic to test below scenario.

I have an output as below let's say table name temp

```
BUSINESS_KEY     STATUS_KEY   CREATE_TIMESTAMP
123               a1          1 P.M.
123               a1          1:30 P.M.
123               b1          2:00 P.M.
123               a1          2:30 P.M.
```

I have to pick up below records out of the above

```
BUSINESS_KEY     STATUS_KEY   CREATE_TIMESTAMP
123               a1          1 P.M.
123               b1          2:00 P.M.
123               a1          2:30 P.M.
```

I have to discard second record, the rule is if the same status_key comes in output for consecutive timestamps as it was in the example above 1:00 P.M. and 1:30 P.M., only the earliest timestamp record is picked up. I am allowed to pick the fourth record as it's not consecutive to the first one.

I tried all rank(), row_number, self join combinations, but did not work. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I just answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142981/how-to-group-this-data-so-i-can-pull-out-specific-rows-from-each-group/42145336#42145336) using `LAG` and `ROW_NUMBER()`. I would suggest storing that TIMESTAMP as a `DATETIME` though... because ordering your data across days will cause you some headaches. What if the time was 11:50 and then 00:01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `lag()`, another uses difference of `row_number()`.  The latter is appropriate for pre-SQL Server 2012.  With `lag()` this is easy:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(status_key) over (partition by business_key order by create_timestamp) as prev_status_key
      from t
     ) t
where prev_status_key is null or prev_status_key <> status_key;
```